# Android TV application doesn't support Amazon FireTV

Tags: android, android-tv, android-studio-2.3, amazon-fire-tv

While creating android TV app the minimum sdk level we can select is api-21(Lollipop). But for creating android TV app from android studio that also supports amazon fireTV we have to select the minimum sdk level to api-17 (Jellybean),

[image]

[image]

```
 As the amazon fire TV add-on is available in api-17.
```

Can anyone please correct me if I am wrong/ Please help me out how can I create app that supports fire TV.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Amazon FireTV for testing and a default Android Studio TV project and it runs just fine, maybe your problem isn't the sdk but the source itself.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the manifest with this once this is done you can tick the fire tv devices . This sets that this fire tv doesn't need touch screen.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
```